# First two values of list to currency

Tags: c#, string, model-view-controller

I have a list of strings filled with decimal's in which only the first two values of it must be currency while the others have to take the decimals out.

This is the list of strings:

```
2451.37
1678.00
12.00
90.00
10.00
```

I need to make the output to be:

```
$2,451.37
$1,678.00
12
90
10
```

I have tried this:

```
 <h4 class="semi-bold">
        @if (haveDataDay)
        { 
            @valueDateDay.ToString(valueDateDay % 1 == 0 ? "N0" : "C2") }
        else
        { @this.FP("lbl.loader.nodata") }
    </h4>
</div>
```

But this only makes currency the values that have decimals other than "**.00**", but sometimes my list has the first two values with "**.00**" in which case they don't get the currency change.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you not enrich that list of strings into objects that contain the requisite attributes? That way your converter/formatter logic can be so much simpler... and possibly a bit more MVVM-friendly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your strings to doubles, then use built-in formatting tools. There are .NET methods to handle both currency and rounding/digit truncation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace CurrencyFormatting_StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var strings = new List<string>()
            {
                "2451.37",
                "1678.00",
                "12.00",
                "90.00",
                "10.00"
            };
            FormatStrings(strings);
            string display = string.Join("\n", strings);
            Console.WriteLine(display);
            /*
            * $2,451.37
            * $1,678.00
            * 12
            * 90
            * 10
            */
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void FormatStrings(List<string> strings)
        {
            int index = 0;
            for (; index < 2; index++)
            {
                string s = strings[index];
                double d = double.Parse(s);
                string currency = d.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
                strings[index] = currency;
            }
            for (; index < strings.Count; index++)
            {
                string s = strings[index];
                double d = double.Parse(s);
                double rounded = Math.Round(d, 2);
                strings[index] = rounded + "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```